# split a string in Perl into a database

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I use the code:

```
$data_read=$port_obj->read($buffer);
print "$data_read\n";
```

The output look like this:

```
T=3420499518  A=914 B=97 C=49 D=436 E=428 F=863 G=34 H=771 I=214 J=493 K=165
```

I want to put it in this:

```
$T,$A,$B,$C,$D,$E,$F,$G,$H,$I,$J,$K
```

So I can write it to a MySQL database. How do I do it ?

My Database handler :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myhouse (T,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K)
          VALUES ($T,$A,$B,$C,$D,$E,$F,$G,$H,$I,$J,$K)";

$query_handle = $connect->prepare($query);

$query_handle->execute();
```

Comment: You should not interpolate variables in queries. Use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) instead.

Comment: If they're all numeric, there isn't much danger, but the validation that they _are_ all numeric should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like it this way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data_read = "T=3420499518  A=914 B=97 C=49 D=436 E=428 F=863 G=34 H=771 I=214 J=493 K=165";
my %data = split(/\s+|=/, $data_read);

my @cols = keys %data;
my $cols = join(', ', @cols);
my $placeholders = join(', ', ('?')x scalar @cols );

my $query = "INSERT INTO table ($cols) VALUES ($placeholders)";
    # execute like this:
# $dbh->do($query, undef, @data{@cols});

print "$query\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

You should store the data values in a hash, use placeholders in the prepared SQL statement, and pass a hash slice to the `execute` method.

The code looks like this

```
my $data_read = 'T=3420499518  A=914 B=97 C=49 D=436 E=428 F=863 G=34 H=771 I=214 J=493 K=165';

my %data = $data_read =~/([A-Z0-9]+)/g;

my $query_handle = $connect->prepare(<<SQL);
INSERT INTO myhouse (T,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
SQL

$query_handle->execute(@data{ qw/ T A B C D E F G H I J K / });
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending on comments to Jonathan Leffler's answer, [perldoc keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) tells us that:

> The keys of a hash are returned in an apparently random order. The
>   actual random order is subject to change in future versions of Perl,
>   but *it is guaranteed to be the same order as either the `values` or `each`
>   function produces* (given that the hash has not been modified).

(emphasis mine)  This means we can use a hash to collect all the field names and their associated values without needing to explicitly enumerate them in the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in = 'T=3420499518  A=914 B=97 C=49 D=436 E=428 F=863 G=34 H=771 I=214 J=493 K=165';

my %data = $in =~ /([A-Z])=([0-9]+)/g;

my $query = 'INSERT INTO myhouse (' . join(',', keys %data)
          . ') VALUES (' . join(',', values %data) . ')';

say $query;
```

(Note that, as TLP mentioned in a comment on the original question, this is *only* safe because the regex which fills `%data` guarantees us that the keys will all be single uppercase letters and the values will consist solely of English-language digits.  If there's any possibility that malicious input could result in uncontrolled keys or values in `%data`, then you need to hardcode the field names and use placeholders for the values unless you want a visit from [little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that putting them into the individually named variables is the best choice, but the customer is always right:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data_read = "T=3420499518  A=914 B=97 C=49 D=436 E=428 F=863 G=34 H=771 I=214 J=493 K=165";

my $data = $data_read;
$data =~ s/[A-KT]=//g;

print "$data\n";

my($T,$A,$B,$C,$D,$E,$F,$G,$H,$I,$J,$K) = split /\s+/, $data;

my $query = "INSERT INTO myhouse (T,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K) VALUES\n" .
            "($T,$A,$B,$C,$D,$E,$F,$G,$H,$I,$J,$K)";

print "$query\n";

print "\nAlternative:\n";
my(@list) = split /\s+/, $data;
print "@list\n";

my $query2 = "INSERT INTO myhouse (T,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K)\nVALUES(" .
             join(",", @list) . ")";

print "$query2\n";
```

When this snippet is run, it produces:

```
3420499518  914 97 49 436 428 863 34 771 214 493 165
INSERT INTO myhouse (T,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K) VALUES
(3420499518,914,97,49,436,428,863,34,771,214,493,165)

Alternative:
3420499518 914 97 49 436 428 863 34 771 214 493 165
INSERT INTO myhouse (T,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K)
VALUES(3420499518,914,97,49,436,428,863,34,771,214,493,165)
```

The second half of the script shows a simpler alternative, using an array to hold the values read in.

Clearly, you can check that values were assigned to all the variables and other such error checking if you wish.

Comment: I was thinking that using a hash would be optimal, but I'm not sure that the field names can be inserted with placeholders.. e.g. `my %data = map { split /=/ } split ' ', $data; .... $dbh->execute(keys %data, values %data);` I do believe that while hashes do not preserve order, they do keep the same non-order between keys and values.

Comment: I vaguely wondered about using a hash, but decided that the guaranteed positional nature of the array suited the positional inputs.  You would have to get the keys into the prepared statement in the correct order, AFAIK, and then get the values into the list.  I think that the `$dbh->execute()` notation you should should generate a mismatch between the number of values expected and the number provided; Perl doesn't have a way to distinguish two lists from one list, and SQL doesn't provide a suitable mechanism either.

Comment: Tnx  Jonathan Leffler.. it works... The best version looks like the "Alternative"  - There is still a smaller issue :

Comment: The issue is there is a "," in the beginning: The output looks like this now: INSERT INTO myhouse (T,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K) VALUES (,1113314430,365,432,450,453,448,457,771,214,493,165)

Comment: DOH!!!  I just need something like : 
 perl -le '$_="\n,1113314430"; s/.//; print'